# ¿Como hacer que jquery validate muestre los mensajes de error con un símbolo de font-awesome?

Tags: jquery, html5, jquery-validate, font-awesome

He estado intentando hacer que jQuery validate me de un mensaje de error debajo del input text cuando el campo de texto se deja en blanco. Y que se muestre un símbolo delante, para darle mas notoriedad, como en el formulario de registro de Google, pero no funciona. Dejo el codepen con el código que he intentado hasta ahora. https://codepen.io/Xefiron/pen/EMMzbo

Comment: El icono se muestra correctamente, lo que pasa es que al darle un `display:none` al div **state** no se muestra

Comment: Es que la idea es que el icono se muestre junto con el texto de error cuando este aparezca.

Comment: Debes controlar eso mediante JQuery idealmente colega

Comment: Pero es el validate quien controla eso de mostrar o no el mensaje, y no me funciona la validación para hacer el campo requerido. Cuando presiono el botón no hace nada, y eso que ya implemente las reglas y el mensaje. Incluso puse el wrapper indicando que debe aparecer en ese div.